# What were the reactions of the former Bounty crew on the discovery of the Pitcairn islanders?

Tags: age-of-sail

The [Pitcairn island colony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitcairn_Islands) was discovered by whalers in 1808 and later by the Royal Navy in 1814. At that time several former crew members of the Bounty, including Bligh, were still alive. Is it known of any one of them becoming aware of the fate of the mutineers and commenting it?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786).